# -bash: nodenv: command not found

Tags: node.js

I was having trouble getting `nodenv` to use the version of node I wanted. I uninstalled node, so that now when I run `which node` I get nothing.

the problem is now when I try to install using `nodenv` it doesn't work.

```
$ nodenv install 9.11.1
-bash: nodenv: command not found
```

To double check that `nodenv` is actually installed, I ran this:

```
$ brew install nodenv
Warning: nodenv 1.2.0 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.2.0, run `brew reinstall nodenv`
```

per https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv

```
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv-installer/raw/master/bin/nodenv-doctor | bash
Checking for `nodenv' in PATH: not found
  Please refer to https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv#installation
```

**EDIT **

I had to uninstall and reinstall nodenv

Comment: Have you checked the output of your `PATH` variable? Something like `echo $PATH`? Or `which nodenv`? The path *should* be in `/usr/local/bin/` which is Homebrew’s default install path.

Comment: @JakeGould I just removed everything from ~/.zshrc and uninstalled nodenv, after reinstalling I am close to a working version. I still don't have `nodenv install` working even though I have `node-build` installed

Comment: @Imo523, it is possible that nodenv needs a default copy of NodeJS installed on the system. I would've try removing nodenv, reinstalling default node and installing nodenv again.

Comment: @imo523 also, if you have solved the problem, please post a detailed answer. To help future readers. Thanks!